# What is Vern's role at the recovery house?

Tags: character, recovery-road

In the 2015 series [*Recovery Road*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_Road_(TV_series)), Craig is the main counselor at the recovery house. However, I am a little confused about Vern. Does he have some sort of administrative role too or is he just another resident?

It seems strange to me that Craig would be the only person with authority at the house (who runs the place if he gets sick?), and Vern kind of seems like his right hand man. He is the most together compared to the other residents and I don't think I've seen him mention an addiction. He is often providing advice as well. And in episode 3, Vern goes through the gifts that Maddie's mom brings to make sure that everything is okay, which seems odd for a resident to do, but less so if he were in charge.

So what is Vern's role at the recovery house?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Episode 4, "Parties without Borders", has a greater focus on Vern. It shows his past as an addict, and the day that he arrived at the sobriety house. It seems he is still in recovery as well, given that he mentions that he has to deal with mandatory check-ins and that he has 3 years sobriety. Rebecca also works out a deal to get a single room at the house ahead of Vern, so he is still a resident.